# Listen to insert_keyframe event using python

Tags: python, keyframes, operator, depsgraph

I can't figure out how to listen to a keyframe insert event in an armature and retrieve the newly inserted keyframe(s) using a callback. Msgbus, Depsgraph, Modal ?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: One way is: `bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(fx)`, fx will run when certain key frames added or doing some behaviors in UI. But it will not trigger when adding a keyframe from a script.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i have the feeling that i can't really use that to do heavy computation on the callback because it is firing way too many times like every time you move or rotate a bone.